# Which test to use when comparing two variables of which one has multiple levels?

Tags: r, anova, t-test, multilevel-analysis, group-differences

Here's some example data:

```
data_ex <- data.frame( pnum = rep(1:30),
                       variable_1 = floor(runif(30, min=0, max=101)),
                       variable_2a = floor(runif(30, min=0, max=101)),
                       variable_2b = floor(runif(30, min=0, max=101)),
                       variable_2c = floor(runif(30, min=0, max=101)))
```

I want to run a statistical test to check for the differences between variable 1 and 2, while I'm also interested in knowing the difference between the different levels of variables 2 (a,b,c). 
I could run two analyses: first a simple t-test between variable 1 and the average of the 3 variable 2's. Then run an anova to compare between the three levels of variable 2. However, I believe there must be a way to answer my questions with one (more sophisticated) test, would anyone have a suggestion on how to do this?

Comment: Is there some kind of outcome you are predicting?

Comment: Not in this example data, but in the actual data, I would expect a significant difference between variable 1 and combined variable 2, where I expect variable 1 to be larger than 2. Then a group difference between the three levels of variable 2, I have no a priori expectation of the direction but any group difference would be interesting